# Showing hidden divs on mouseover

Tags: html, hidden, jsfiddle

I have a jsfiddle with some code. Very simply, when I move the mouse over one div (triggerShowHidePanel) another hidden div below (categoryContainer1) is shown. Move the mouse away and categoryContainer1 disappears.

To make the code a bit more useful, I intend to add more than one set of these, which I created on the jsfiddle. The problem is that it always shows/hides categoryContainer1 rather than categoryContainer2/3/4 etc. Am I missing something obvious?

http://jsfiddle.net/gUap5/24/

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div style='float:left; width:50px;' class='triggerShowHidePanel' panelID='1'>first</div>
  <div style='float:left; width:50px;' class='triggerShowHidePanel' panelID='2'>second </div>
  <div style='float:left; width:50px;' class='triggerShowHidePanel' panelID='3'>third </div>
  <div style='float:left; width:50px;' class='triggerShowHidePanel' panelID='4'>forth </div>

  <div class='categoryContainer1' style='float:left; display:none; width:100px;'>
    1st
  </div>    
  <div class='categoryContainer2' style='float:left; display:none; width:100px;'>
    2nd
  </div>
  <div class='categoryContainer3' style='float:left; display:none; width:100px;'>
    3rd
  </div>
  <div class='categoryContainer4' style='float:left; display:none; width:100px;'>
    4th 
  </div>

</div>
```

Script

```
$('.container').bind('mouseover', function() {
    var ele = $(this).find(".triggerShowHidePanel");
    var positionX = ele.position().top + 30;
    var positionY = ele.position().left;
    $('.categoryContainer' + ele.attr('panelID')).show();
    $('.categoryContainer' + ele.attr('panelID')).offset({ 
        top: Math.round(positionX), 
        left: Math.round(positionY)
    });     
}).bind('mouseout', function() {
    var ele = $(this).find(".triggerShowHidePanel");
    $('.categoryContainer' + ele.attr('panelID')).hide();
    $('.categoryContainer' + ele.attr('panelID')).offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the general problem is that you bind the mouseover event to the  element. 
In this case, everytime you move the mouse over the container you will always get the panelID of the first element which uses the class ".triggerShowHidePanel". You could bind the mouseover to the ".triggerShowHidePanel" class this might fix the problem you encountered

```
$('.triggerShowHidePanel').bind('mouseover', function() {
var ele = $(this);
var positionX = ele.position().top + 30;
var positionY = ele.position().left;
$('.categoryContainer' + ele.attr('panelID')).show();
$('.categoryContainer' + ele.attr('panelID')).offset({ 
    top: Math.round(positionX), 
    left: Math.round(positionY)
});     
}).bind('.triggerShowHidePanel', function() {
    var ele = $(this);
    $('.categoryContainer' + ele.attr('panelID')).hide();
    $('.categoryContainer' + ele.attr('panelID')).offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });
});
```